# The Sciatic Nerve and Fat of Kosher Fowl

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, kashering-kosherization, poultry, chelev

I have learned that the sciatic nerve must be removed from land animals to render the meat kosher. But what about fowl? Does the sciatic nerve need to be removed from chicken or turkey? Why or why not?

I have also learned that certain fats need to be removed from domestic land animals. Does this apply to fowl in any way?

Comment: Max, welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks for bringing your question here! I hope you'll look around the site and find other material to your taste, perhaps including our 300+ other [tag:kosher] questions. Also, please consider [registering](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/login) your account, which will [give you access](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) to more of the site's features.

Answer (score 5):

No. The [Chelev](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chelev) prohibitions do not apply to fowl (ShA YD [64:1](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=yd_x3659)). The [Gid Hanasheh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gid_hanasheh) prohibition would only apply to a fowl which has a "circular hip joint", though there is no need to check fowl for such a joint (ibid. [65:5](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=yd_x4133)) and I am unaware of any commonly consumed fowl which have such a joint.